# How to prevent second OS X partition from seeing apps in the other partition?

Tags: macos, applications, install, partition

I have two partitions set up on my MacBook and I'm having issues when installing software on the new partition as it says it is already installed. The application is installed on the other partition but should not be recognised by the new partition.

Is there a way to disable that partitions ability to see the apps etc. from the original partition?

Comment: do both partitions contain system folders (e.g. dual boot Mavericks/Yosemite)?

Comment: The original partition is Yosemite Beta 2/3 and the new one is Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

Unmounting the 'unwanted' partition before installing the new application should help in most cases:

1. Quit all open applications
2. Start `Terminal.app` and enter `diskutil list`

output looks like this:

```
 #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER
 0: GUID_partition_scheme *121.3 GB disk0
 1: EFI 209.7 MB disk0s1
 2: Apple_HFS Yosemite 60.2 GB disk0s2
 3: Apple_HFS Mavericks 60.3 GB disk0s3
 4: Apple_Boot Recovery HD 650.0 MB disk0s4
```

3. determine the identifier of the partition to unmount by size/volume name and enter `diskutil unmount /dev/IDENTIFIER`
   (in the above case `diskutil unmount /dev/disk0s2` to unmount the 'Yosemite' partition)
4. To remount this partition afterwards just enter `diskutil mount /dev/disk0s2`

Comment: Thanks for this. Will it automatically remount again on reboot?

Comment: yes, it will remount automatically

Answer (score 0):

Two more methods:

Disk Utility will allow you unmount single partitions or drives.
After you've done the install/update, Disk Utility will also let you remount the partition without reboot.

Dragging one partition of a multipartition drive to the trash will bring up a dialog asking if you want to unmount just the one partition, or all of them.
To get the partition remounted after install/update, you'll still have to reboot, use Terminal, or Disk Utility.